# Plotting histogram with pandas using variables from a loop

Tags: python-2.7, histogram, pandas-groupby

I am trying to plot an histogram that shows the mean of spendings from each month. From my table, I have more than one value for each month.

month=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
for k in range(0,12):
    DataMonth=pd.Series(df.Spendings).where(df.Month==month[k])

```
print "The average spending in ",month[k]," is", DataMonth.mean()
```

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Jan', 2], ['Feb', 3], ['Jan', 8]], 
    columns=['Month', 'Spendings']
)
```

First compute the mean spendings :

```
mean_spendings = df.groupby('Month').Spendings.mean()
```

Then plot a bar chart (I don't think you want a histogram):

```
mean_spendings.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```